# iOS Objective C : How to increase number of rows after given condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am very new to iOS, Living in a very small village with no help on iOS,
 I need help in my code where I can increase number of rows once I reach to row number 20.

I actually have more than 6000 lines, when try to show all of them in tableview, it takes lot of time, so I want to load all rows in efficient way, like increasing it like +20, +50 etc

here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return a;
}
```

and I am trying to increase rows like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 20)
    {
        [_myTable reloadData];
        [self.myTable beginUpdates];

        a= a +50;
        [self.myTable endUpdates];
    }

    if (indexPath.row > 60)
    {
        [self.myTable beginUpdates];
        a= a +100;
        [self.myTable endUpdates];
    }
}
```

I declared myTable as property

I am sorry if my post is looking foolish I am at very basic position and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Where you are getting number of row's form database ?

Comment: You can keep a load more button on the bottom and let the user click it and when he clicks load the contents to your data source array and reload the table

Comment: I am taking data from from json file, it is working nicely if i am only showing 20 to 50 rows

Comment: Or another way is keep a loading symbol in your last cell and when the last cell is reached you can do the same process as I described in above comment

Comment: for `numberOfRowsInSection`, provide count of your dataSource array. For increasing the rows, add a data object in your dataSource array and then reload the tableview. Nothing to do at all

Comment: @Arun Sir I want to load it without button, but its not working, I dont know what code should i do there

Comment: @FahadAli See Sathi Reddy's answer below. That is the correct answer for your situation

Comment: Agree with @NSNoob. Follow the answer. Add the data what you want to load in your table view into an array and return its count in numberOfRowsInSection method. Whenever you need to add more data, add it to this array and reload table view :)

Comment: When you say you want to fetch the data periodically, that stuff is called Pagination. Pagination should be implemented on Server's end, or if you are doing it all offline, then on client. Moreover, use `dequeueTableViewCellWithIdentifier` method to load cells to reduce memory usage. Also, perform fetching operations on background thread.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating your `UITableViewCell` items. It sounds as if you are not reusing your cells and allocating them all from scratch. 6000 cells shouldn't cause much of a problem.

Comment: Suggest you learn more knowledge points on UItableView's reusage before you confirm your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers of rows to be displayed in a tableView depends on data available i.e., the data to be displayed in the `UITableView`.

Let an array "Countries" containing list of 3 countries:

```
NSArray *countries;

countries  = @[@"India",@"USA",@"Germany",nil];
```

so, now the `UITableView` has 3 rows, so use this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return countries.count;
}
```

so if the countries list increased later, then it will work.

No need to increase number of rows in table manually.

If the response is from server, then use this:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"countriesJson"];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return dataArray.count;
}
```

### Sample Project:

Please check my GitHub link below:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/TableRowCountDynamic

Note: More images are loaded if we reach a certain limit.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, But my json file has more than 6000 list, so when i use myjson.count , it directly start loading list of 6000+, so it takes around 3minutes to load, so that i want to increase number of rows step by step

Comment: @FahadAli That's your server's flawed implementation. That will waste time and resources. Tell them to implement pagination on Server's end and get smaller chunks of data.

Comment: @FahadAli  Does your parameters that are sending to server in API call contains limit? If  limit is provided, then we can retrieve data (the number of records) as you want per API call

Comment: If not provided as @NSNoob said "It was your backend problem"

Comment: @SathiReddy Sir, actually the offline database i have, is in json format, so i am just copying that json in an array, and loading that array in tableView,

Comment: @SathiReddy so, in numbersOfRowsInSection, I was returning the array.count, that has more than 6000 entries , so i am searching for the way to not load all 6000 entries at a time, but as 30, 40 rows

Comment: @Fahad Ali   you are retrieving data from offline i.e.., not from server?  If your data is ready to display, then i will tell u the solution..

Comment: yeah please, i have offline json file that is working fine

Comment: @Fahad Ali   please check my link.. It is a partial and sample answer. In this sample, loader is not working, i will update it as soon as possible..

Comment: @Fahad Ali We cannot see the loader because the data loads quickly. If the data is loading slowly, then we can see the loader..

Comment: @SathiReddy ohh great, you made the perfect sample code, i am really thankful, there are some little things that i didnt get, i must spend some time on it to understand, Thanks Alot Sir

Answer (score -1):

You have to follow below algorithm or logic,

1)First just initialize your array with the 20 objects and that array will use for the display in a `UITableView` as a `datasource`.

2)Then you need to implement the `UIScrollView delegate` method, `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView` in which you can write a some code like this:

```
- (Void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) aScrollView
{
    self.tbleSerachResult.frame=self.tbleSerachResult.frame;

    if (aScrollView==self.tblOutlet) {
        [currentTextfield resignFirstResponder];

        CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
        CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
        UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
        float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
        float h = size.height;
        float reload_distance = 10;
        if(y > h + reload_distance)
        {   
            //add more 20 records to your existing array which used for the UITableView data source and reload the UITableView.
            //Put your load more data method here...

        }
    }
 }
```

3) after this, you doesn't require any other thing to maintain this. Just implement the `UITableView delegate` and `datasource` methods as normally. It will work.

Try this way, if still facing any issue let me know I will give you example code.

Hope it works for you!! Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks alott :) I am trying it now